# Different outdated versions living alongside in Cellar

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I've found two versions of mongodb in the Cellar folder, they are both outdated (I can't upgrade to the latest one due to outdated OS 10.10.3 + XCode conflicts) but `brew cleanup` does nothing to get rid of the older one.

This is part of the output of `brew info mongodb`:

```
mongodb: stable 4.0.3 [pinned at 3.4.9]
High-performance, schema-free, document-oriented database
https://www.mongodb.com/
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.10 (18 files, 248.2MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-11-09 at 01:42:15
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.9 (18 files, 288.5MB) *
  Built from source on 2017-10-17 at 08:54:34
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mongodb.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: go ✘, pkg-config ✔, scons ✔
Required: openssl ✔, python@2 ✘
==> Requirements
Build: xcode ✘
```

As you can see I already tried `brew pin`ing it to some version and then cleaning up, to no avail.

Is there a reason why Brew would keep both? Does this mean there might be packages, each one dependent on different versions? Is there a way to figure this out and (gracefully) getting rid of any unused version?

Comment: maybe you need "brew uninstall --force mongodb" and install again new version

Comment: Thanks but as I said before, I can't upgrade/install the latest one due to outdated OS 10.10.3 + XCode conflicts.

Comment: ups, maybe you need  prehistoric times... you can find like to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula